# angular cli npm run test with chrome

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-runner

I try to run angular cli karma test in Chrome to get a localhost link. 
but if i run  npm run test it open chrome and close it immediately.

karma.config.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath:                 '',
        frameworks:               ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
        plugins:                  [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('karma-junit-reporter'),
            require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
        ],
        client:                   {
            clearContext: false
        },
        files:                    [{
            pattern: './src/test.ts',
            watched: false
        }],
        preprocessors:            {
            './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
        },
        mime:                     {
            'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            reports:               ['html', 'lcovonly'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
        },
        angularCli:               {
            config:      './.angular-cli.json',
            environment: 'dev'
        },
        reporters:                config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
            ? ['progress', 'junit', 'coverage-istanbul']
            : ['progress', 'junit', 'kjhtml'],
        junitReporter:            {
            outputDir:      'test/target',
            outputFile:     'surefire-reports/TEST-karma.xml',
            suite:          '',
            useBrowserName: true
        },

        port:                     9876,
        colors:                   true,
        logLevel:                 config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch:                true,
        browsers:                 [
            //'PhantomJS',
            'Chrome'
        ],
        singleRun:                true
    });
};
```

How can run npm run test in chrome.

I try to to get localhost with all my tests so that i can debug it in vs code.

console output:

```
10% building modules 2/2 modules 0 active10 02 2018 23:45:02.459:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
10 02 2018 23:45:02.462:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
10 02 2018 23:45:02.468:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome                                                                                      10 02 2018 23:45:12.031:INFO [Chrome 64.0.3282 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket QFzL8LOUHJtjA405AAAA with id 83404421
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 28 of 28 SUCCESS (0.976 secs / 0.951 secs)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can always run `ng test`

Comment: Can you also post console output when you hit `ng test`?

Comment: The CLI *karma.config.js* doesn't have the junit additions in it right out of the box, so that may a good thing to remove and start over from there.

Comment: @abdul-wahab see console output in the post. the problem is that the test server close  immediately.

Comment: Well, at least the unit tests are succeeding! :) Try changing `singleRun` to false in the *karma.config.js* to see if you get any more feedback from the browser.

Comment: @R.Richards Thanks that is what i am looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is this=> "if i run npm run test it open chrome and close it immediately"
That's because of this=> **singleRun=true**
When it is true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits.
So change that to

**singleRun: false**